# WPF/C# : How to binding Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Dictionary<string1, Dictionary<string2, string3>> for receive data from server.

string1 is the name for 28 units to receive a total of 28 bundles of data from the server.
string2 is name for the data items and string3 is value of data items. So I collected the data as below.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> All_Unit = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> Each_Unit = new Dictionary<string, string>();

~~~ // Save data receive from server that items name in key of Each_Unit and real data value in value of Each_Unit.

All_Unit.Add(UnitName, Each_Unit);
```

The number of 28 units is always fixed, but the number of data items received from each unit can change.
So I used dictionary to receive and save the data dynamically without modifying source.
Actually, I think the items to show in datagrid will be key and value of Each_Unit. Perhaps the UnitName is added to the first column.

Anyway, Is it possible to bind data of type dictionary<string,dictionary<string,string>? because I want to display information in datagrid using autogeneratecolumns so that modification is not required on the UI side. If possible, could you tell me how to binding in datagrid?

Comment: Can't you just flatten this into a `DataTable`?  If not, or not desirable, why?

Comment: @Kane.K How do you want to show the data? If you express the data type you want to show, I will make a sample for you.